# Python get datetime of next occurring time

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to find the NEXT datetime where a specific time occurs.

For example:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now() # April 5th, 1 PM
desired_time = '14:00:00' # 2 PM
next_datetime_occurance = get_next_datetime(now, desired_time) # Returns April 5th, 2PM

now = datetime.datetime.now() # April 5th, 3 PM
desired_time = '14:00:00' # 2 PM
next_datetime_occurance = get_next_datetime(now, desired_time) # Returns April 6th, 2PM
```

How would I do this in a clean manner? (Assume everything is in UTC)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `datetime.replace()` with some datetime arithmetic:

```
import datetime as dt

def next_datetime(current: dt.datetime, hour: int, **kwargs) -> dt.datetime:
    repl = current.replace(hour=hour, **kwargs)
    while repl <= current:
        repl = repl + dt.timedelta(days=1)
    return repl
```

Demo:

```
>>> now = dt.datetime.utcnow()
>>> now
datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 7, 20, 17, 21, 581402)
>>> next_datetime(now, hour=19)
datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 8, 19, 17, 21, 581402)
>>> next_datetime(now, hour=21)
datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 7, 21, 17, 21, 581402)
>>> next_datetime(now, hour=20, minute=12)
datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 8, 20, 12, 21, 581402)
>>> next_datetime(now, hour=20, minute=50)
datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 7, 20, 50, 21, 581402)
```

Here `**kwargs` is designed to take `datetime()` constructor parameters that are a higher resolution than `hour`, e.g. minutes, seconds, and microseconds.  You may want to provide some validation of that, since passing something like `year` doesn't make sense given the question.